# Program crashes when converting C++ code to C

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I came across an interesting algorithm which I am having difficulty implementing in C.

I did find the code for it in C++ but I tried converting the C++ code to C but the program crashes.

C++ code below:

```
int BalancedPartition ( int a[] , int n ){

    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        sum += a[i];

    int *s = new int[sum+1];

    s[0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < sum+1 ; i++)    s[i] = 0;

    int diff = INT_MAX , ans;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = sum ; j >= a[i] ; j--)
        {
            s[j] = s[j] | s[j-a[i]];
            if( s[j] == 1 )
            {
                if( diff > abs( sum/2 - j) )
                {
                    diff = abs( sum/2 - j );
                    ans = j;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    cout<< ans << " " << sum-ans<< endl; //two balanced partitions

    return min( ans , sum-ans );
}
```

My (partial) C code is below:

```
double WeightDifference(int *a, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += *a[i];

    }

    const sizeOfS = sum + 1;
    int *s[32467];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `int *s[32467];` creates a huge array of pointers to integers. You probably want `int s[32467];`. The C++ syntax is because of `new`.

Comment: The array in your C and C++ code behaves the same, so it's just `sum += a[i]`. Dereferencing that with an additional `*` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: `*a[i];` no need for the `*`

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your reply, the code crashes later too. Would it be possible for any of you to upload the C code by any chance?

Comment: Except your output via streams and the array creation with `new`, your C++ code should be fine as C code. If you use a `malloc`/`free` combo instead of `new`or a varable-length array and use `printf` instead of those pesky `<<`s, you should be fine.

Comment: @user3353723 Your C++ code has a memory leak.  Maybe you should fix your C++ code before converting it to C.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie where is the memory leak?

Comment: @user3353723 Where do you call `delete[]`?  You call `new[]` and nowhere do you call `delete[]` to deallocate the memory.

Comment: @user3353723 - To avoid the leak use `std::vector<int>` instead of `new[]`.  Otherwise the C++ version you have is wrong -- it needs to be fixed as it will cause all sorts of memory issues if it is called repeatedly and/or `sum` is very large.

Comment: cool thanks for that Paul. all fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

`sum += *a[i];`

is certainly wrong since a is `a` pointer and you already accessed its element using the `[]` operator. Drop the unneeded dereference( `*` operator ).

`int *s[32467];`

You probably mean to make an array of ints not array of pointers to int.

`int s[32467];`

Comment: Works. cheers for that

Answer (score 1):

In a C program you can't use a loop like

```
for(int i=0....),
```

First initialize a variable

```
int i=0;
```

then continue with your loop like:

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {...whatever you want to do in the loop...}
```

Comment: In C99, you can. There's also no need to initialise `i` before it is used in the loop.

Comment: This does not cause the crash.

Answer (score 1):

The "new" operator is C++ only, so you need to replace it with calloc:

```
int *s = calloc(sum+1,sizeof(int));
```

instead of

```
int *s = new int[sum+1];
```

"cout" is an object specific to C++, so replace it with printf:

```
printf("%d %d \n",ans,sum-ans);  /* two balanced partitions */
```

instead of

```
cout<< ans << " " << sum-ans<< endl; // two balanced partitions
```

The C compiler needs to know where to find calloc and INT_MAX so these 
included are necessary:

```
/* for malloc or calloc */
#include <stdlib.h>
/* for INT_MAX */
#include <limits.h>
```

You may need to add a min function:

```
int min(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < b) 
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}
```

If you aren't using a C99 compiler, as mentioned in another answer, 
the index variables in the for loop need to be declared at the top of the function rather than in the for loop. You may also need to move all variable declarations to the top as well if your compiler is older and rejects them intermixed with code.

Comment: My C program gives wrong output if the elements  of `a[]` are even..would you know to fix this?

Comment: +1 for your answer though. Will tick it for the accepted answer if the even element issue is sorted

Comment: @user3353723 Does the C++ code as presented give the correct answer when compiled as C++ and input even numbers?

Comment: No it doesnt. Would you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? Is the input array of ints supposed to be sorted?

Comment: Hi there, please see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 1):

The original code uses very little C++ specific syntax or semantics and is easily rewritten as C code. Your error is that s refers to a dynamic array of type `int` and you have replaced it with an auto array of type `int*`.

For a direct translation, replace:

```
int* s = new int[sum+1] ;
```

With

```
int* s = malloc( sizeof(int) * (sum + 1) ) ;
```

Alternatively, since the function interface has nothing C++ specific and assuming it is not overloaded you could simply compile the original code as C++ with C linkage:

```
extern "C" int BalancedPartition ( int a[] , int n )
{
   ...
```

Compiled in a .cpp file as C++ then linked to your C code the function can be called as-is.

Another solution is to leave the existing C++ code exactly as it is, and simply re-compile your C code as C++. Most well formed C code will compile as C++ with no changes, or with fewer changes than attempting to translate C++ to C. In many cases compiling your C code as C++ will find bugs too and the type checking in C++ is stricter.

It is often better to interoperate C with C++ that attempt to rewrite it, especially as C++ is a larger language, and many simple constructs get ugly and complex when rendered as C.

Comment: My C program gives wrong output if the elements of a[] are even..would you know to fix this?+1 for your answer though.

Comment: Hi clifford, I cant compile it as C++ because we are told to only include C code for our work project.

Comment: It is probably inappropriate to answer your secondary question posted in a comment.  You should post a further question perhaps, with your actual code (since you have not posted your complete version there is insufficient information).  However, I strongly suggest that you use your toolchain's debugger to step the code and observe teh variable state at each step to determine what is going wrong - that is generally a much more productive debugging approach that posting on SO or a forum.

Comment: @user3353723 : I would caution against using "found code" of unknown provenance or quality as a "resource" for academic assignments. Quite apart from the issue of plagiarism, you are perhaps not equipped to determine the quality of the code, and may not be able to explain or justify its design in your submission (i.e. you will get caught out!).

Comment: @user3353723 : In the real world, no one would place arbitrary restrictions on implementation.  Any solution restrictions imposed upon you for academic reasons should be mentioned in the question, because at face value, your solution (to convert the code to C) is the least best option.  Moreover people need to know if this is essentially a "homework" question in order to avoid "doing it for you" - for which you may also be caught out - already Googling "BalancedPartition" turns up this question as the first hit, any sensible tutor will check Google for "your work".